# Why does the non-capturing group (?:) seem to not be working?

Tags: regex, perl, string

```
my $str='expire=0';

if ($str =~/expire\s*=\s* (?: 0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/){
    print " found it ";
}
```

its not working

Condition `expire=` should be followed by a number between `1-99`?

Comment: Why are you even using a non-capturing group in this pattern?

Comment: To group the "or" expression...why capture if if you don't need to extract it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your regex has spaces, remove them:

```
/expire\s*=\s* (?: 0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/
              ^   ^
```

Also the regex `0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]` does not match `0`.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, you want to allow a number from `1-99` after `expire=` so you can use:

```
/^expire\s*=\s*(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$/
```

or a shorter version:

```
/^expire\s*=\s*(?:[1-9][0-9]?)$/
```

Since your example has `0` after `expire=` it'll not be matched.

Also note that I've added the start and end anchors. Without them the regex may match any valid sub-string of the input. Example it can match `expire=99` in the input `expire=999`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use spaces in your regex without them actually matching spaces, you need to use the `x` modifier on your regex. I.e. `/ foo /x` matches the string "foo", while `/ foo /` only matches " foo ".

Comment: @Josh try it in the real world, with a complex pattern. It's nice to be able to separate related bits, and even break it across lines :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a space between the second \s* and the beginning of the non-capturing group. Try this instead:

```
~/expire\s*=\s*(?:0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/
```